# How to append HTML content with CSS, JS in current webpage using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

For example,

```js
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML = "<p>new content</p><script>alert('Hello World!')</script>";
element.appendChild(newElement);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Result: "new content" is appended in page but there will be no alert saying Hello World!

I have tried innerHTML, insertAdjacentHTML, append, appendChild methods. But the problem is JS and CSS not loading dynamically.

In jQuery, `after()` works

```js
$(selector).after("<p>new content</p><script>alert('Hello World!')</script>");
```

is there any equivalent for pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute your scripts under string formats. jQuery also uses `eval` in some parts of DOM manipulation under the hood.

```js
const content = "<p>new content<\/p><script>alert('Hello World!')<\/script>";
const newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML = content
const scriptRegex = /(?<=<script>)(.*)(?=<\/script>)/g; //get scripts between script tags

const scripts = content.match(scriptRegex);
for(const script of scripts) {
  eval(script) //execute your string as a script
}

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newElement);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Side note, for your case, there is no way called **safety** to convert strings to scripts because somebody may inject malicious scripts into your strings and execute them without your notice, so you need to make sure all your strings are under your control properly. You can check [XSS attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If your are sure about `HTML string` content is `safety` and contains a string with valid HTML you can use [Range.createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) (executes scripts )

```
const HTMLContent = "<p>new content</p><script>alert('Hello World!')</script>";
const newElement = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTMLContent);
document.body.appendChild(newElement)
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7zjmdf)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your alert when something happens, if you want the alert to be displayed when you append the HTML, then wrap it in a self executing function:

```
<script>
    (function(){
      alert('Hello World!');
    })()
</script>
```

Comment: Referred to as an IIFE ([Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)).

Comment: Here i want to append html with dynamic js and css so css/js will apply for current page..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a script or a stylesheet dynamically into your page, you should:

1. create a script/link/style tag
2. edit the tags innerText/innerHTML
3. append the tag to your page's head element

Here's an example to append a script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'some url'; // use this for external scripts
    script.innerHTML = 'your script'; // use this for writing your own script content

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts cannot be added directly to the DOM as HTML text and executed. I would separate the action into two phases. Insert the HTML and add the script to the end of the document body as a contextual fragment.

```js
const insertHTML = (domHTML, scriptHTML, target = document.body) => {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = domHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  document.body.append(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(scriptHTML));
};

const domHTML = `<p>new content<\/p>`;

const scriptHTML = `
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello World!');
  <\/script>
`;

insertHTML(domHTML, scriptHTML);
```

This logic was borrowed from [Tilak Maddy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641523/1762224) response in a related question.